# CXF is not generating "throws RemoteException"

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf

I am trying to migrate to CXF from AXIS. I am facing a lot of differences in code, generated from the same wsdl file (different method arguments list, return types). There is no RemoteException throwing declaration for all methods, generated by CXF.
Any suggestions?
Thanks. Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per JAX-WS spec the methods should not be throwing RemoteException.   They could throw a javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException if something goes wrong, but that is a subclass of RuntimeException and thus doesn't need to be declared.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know something about return types and arguments? There are a lot of differences (void instead of non-void return types, additional arguments)?

Comment: Again, that's JAX-WS spec controlled.  The spec has specific rules for how the method signatures are generated.  That said, you can also try the CXF wsdl2java -bareMethods flag which would change to using the specific wrapper types instead of trying to unwrap them into individual parameters.